# Por que tengo permitido hacer esto?

Tags: c

- Buenas, tenia entendido que la única manera de asignar valores a strings era char por char, pero en vista de lo siguiente...

  ```
  #include<stdio.h>

  int main (){
  char f[5]="Hola";
  printf("%s",f);
  return 0;
  }
  ```
- Ahora estoy bastante confundido, por otro lado, el codigo tambien compila sin poner elementos en el array, es decir...

  ```
  char f[]="Hola";
  ```

-Algun buen samaritano?

Comment: No necesitas poner la dimensión ya que el compilador tiene el largo de la cadena asignada. Usa ese valor para reservar espacio.

Comment: Lo permite porque el lenguaje es así; es un *favor* que te hace. Si fueran números, tendrías que ponerlos entre llaves `int f[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`. Si el tipo es `char`, el compilador te deja usar una cadena literal directamente, que, a fin de cuentas, no es mas que una secuencia de `char` con un `\x00` al final.

Answer (score 0):

Esto:

```
char f[5] = "Hola"
```

No es lo mismo a

```
char f[5];
f = "Hola";
```

En el primer caso el programa crea, generalmente en una región de memoria de solo lectura o en la pila, la cadena "Hola" y, posteriormente, hace que `f` *apunte* a esa dirección de memoria:

```
| ... pila ...  | 0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 | ... pila ...  |
| ... datos ... |  H    o    l    a    \0  | ... datos ... |
```

Efectivamente, has leído bien, esa región de memoria puede ser de solo lectura e intentar modificarla puede tener resultados variopintos: El programa se muere, se produce una excepción, comportamientos erráticos (sobretodo si esa cadena se utiliza en otras partes del programa)... así que sería más correcto declarar la variable así:

```
char const f[5] = "Hola";
```

De esta forma el compilador te avisará ante cualquier intento por modificar el contenido de `f`.

Vale, vamos con el segundo caso:

```
char f[5];
f = "Hola";
```

En este caso estás declarando, generalmente en la pila, la variable `f`, a la cual se le asignan 5 bytes(de la pila). A continuación pretendes que `f`, que es un array, no un puntero, apunte a una región de memoria con el contenido `"Hola"`, que recordemos es contenido **constante**.

```
| ... pila ...  | 0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 | ... | Otra región de memoria |
| ... datos ... |           f[5]           | ... | H   o   l   a  \0
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                         Son regiones de memoria distintas
```

Dicho de otra forma, lo que se pretende con el segundo ejemplo es copiar el texto `"Hola"` en la memoria asignada a `f`. Esta es una operación compleja y tu querido compilador de C no sabe cómo hacerla.

Aunque para tí sea obvio que con ambos casos se pretende lo mismo, piensa que el segundo caso también podría encontrarse así:

```
char f[5];

// Medio centenar de líneas de código aquí...

f = "Hola";
```

¿Y ahora qué? ¿Estamos ante un caso como el primero? ¿sí? ¿no? ni idea. El compilador directamente se lava las manos. Si quieres inicializar el `array` lo haces al declarar dicho array. Piensa que inicializar las variables al declararlas se considera una buena práctica de programación, así que en este caso el compilador te está *empujando* a adquirir buenos hábitos.

Bueno, vamos con el tercer ejemplo:

```
char f[] = "Hola";
```

¿Por qué funciona? ¿Cómo sabe el compilador cuánta memoria necesita `f`? La respuesta es muy sencilla. El compilador sabe que `f` debe contener una cadena de texto muy específica, `"Hola"`, la cual se compone de 5 bytes. Así que se limita a reservar esos 5 bytes para `f` de forma totalmente transparente para ti.

Pero ojo, la cosa cambia si usamos punteros:

```
char * f;
f = "Hola";
```

El siguiente ejempo compila y funciona a la perfección. Lo que sucede ahora es que `f` ya no es un array, sino un puntero. Lo que estamos consiguiendo es que `f` apunte a la región de memoria donde se encuentra la cadena `"Hola"`.

```
| ... pila ...  |                char * f                 | ... | 0x0f45e15a037bb152
| ... datos ... | 0x0f 0x45 0xe1 0x5a 0x03 0x7b 0xb1 0x52 | ... | H o l a \0
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                      Dirección de memoria de la cadena
```

Esta no es la única diferencia entre arrays y punteros, pero tampoco es mi intención escribir un decálogo para poder compararlos. Solo saber que son diferentes y que Internet está plagada de ejemplos y de documentación al respecto.